# gesture on UIImageView hierarchy

Tags: uiimageview, frame

I have a base UIImageView named "A" which can response pinchGesture, and I pinched it, before I addsubview I reset the frame,it looks well. Then I addsubView "B" on base UIImageView "A", but the "B" have the pinched transform of "A", it's big(small). I have reset the frame. Why this has happened.How can I make B show with the origin frame.

```
 - (void)scalePiece:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    [self adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        [gestureRecognizer view].transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], [gestureRecognizer scale], [gestureRecognizer scale]);
        [gestureRecognizer setScale:1];
    }
}

- (void)adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        UIView *piece = gestureRecognizer.view;
        CGPoint locationInView = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:piece];
        CGPoint locationInSuperview = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:piece.superview];

        piece.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(locationInView.x / piece.bounds.size.width, locationInView.y / piece.bounds.size.height);
        piece.center = locationInSuperview;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any suggestion will appreciate

Answer (score 0):

If you apply a transform to a UIView A, that transform will be applied to all its subviews, B in your case. You could try adding B to A's superview if you don't want B to be affected by A's transform.